# How to switch out ItemTemplate for a particular TreeViewItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, itemtemplate

In my scenario, I'd like to be able to have a user double-click on an TreeViewItem to 'edit it'. In which case I would like to have that item expand in place (sliding the TreeViewItems below it down, so layout transform?), and show and edit form in place of the selected item.  So, my question is, can I accomplish this by switching out the ItemTemplate for the double-clicked item?  If so, I'm not sure how to approach this.

I have double-click attached event working on TreeViewItems and I have access to the TreeViewItem in my callback, I would optimally switch out the item's ItemTemplate at that point.  My TreeView is built using a HierarchicalDataTemplate in a static resource for ItemTemplate and ViewModels to back the data.

Any guidance on this approach or any other suggestions to accomplish this scenario are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can change dynamically ItemTemplate for the clicked `TreeViewItem`. 
Do it calling `DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue()`
And do not forget to restore the original local value which you should save before changes. Use `ReadLocalValue()` for this.
You need to define conditions when to restore original template (probably when selection changes.

You can also try to accomplish the task in a more MVVM way.
Just add an attached property `IsDoubleClicked` and set it True for the corresponding `TreeViewItem`.
And add the trigger for the TreeViewItem's `ItemTemplate` bound to the property `IsDoubleClicked`.